# Is there an item that grants Still and Silent spell at the same time?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, metamagic

I'm looking for any item that will allow me to apply both metamagic feats (Still spell and Silent spell) to the same spell without raising the level of the spell slot it costs me.

I would have expected to be able to combine them in a rod at a cost of 9000gp for the lesser version, the same as Burning which has the same level modifier, but I cannot find such an item in the PRD, nor do I see rules for the creation of custom metamagic rods.

Any item which grants these would be acceptable to me. Limited uses per day or requiring me to already possess the feats would not be a problem.

Comment: Won't you need the feat Eschew Materials, too? `;-)`

Comment: @HeyICanChan Sure, but that doesn't increase the spell level (and it's free because I chose the most fun spellcasting class) :-P

Comment: Fair enough. Let those lesser casters [eat spiders](http://dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#spider-climb).

Comment: Would holding two scepters do the trick if you had a way to still be able to cast?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unless I'm misreading the description, I think the item you're looking for is the [Caster's Tattoo](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/tattoo-caster-s/).

> A caster’s tattoo is infused with potential magical energy that aids in casting spells that normally utilize verbal and somatic components. **Once per day, a spellcaster may activate her caster’s tattoo as a swift action to automatically enhance the next spell she casts in that round with both the Still Spell and Silent Spell feats.** When she casts the spell, the caster’s tattoo flares with light for a moment, then grows faint and faded—it replenishes its energy in 24 hours, after which it becomes bold and colorful and can be used again. Required material components or foci must be in the creature’s possession to cast the spell (and are consumed as normal), but need not be held when the spell is cast.
>
> Caster’s tattoos are available in lesser, standard, and greater versions, allowing the modified casting of a spell of up to 3rd level, 6th level, or 9th level respectively.

Its only once per day, but nothing stops you from getting multiples if you're dedicated to having this capability.

Comment: This is precisely what I'm looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As long as your GM does not disallow custom item creation, find a Crafter Mage to custom create a rod that has both (or have a Mage add one to a rod that already has the other).

This will take money and time since it will take time to create.  But with some planning, you can get it.